# Write user friendly url in htaccess with get parameters

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have a query in my site

```
myexample.com/search/?service=abc&location=Dichaon-Kalan-Gdbot
```

How can rewrite in .htaccess to make url user friendly

```
myexample.com/search/abc/Dichaon-Kalan-Gdbot
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a .htaccess file at the root for your files with the following lines:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/search/abc/([a-zA-Z0-9_\ \-\'éèàùûêâôë]*)$ /search/?service=abc&location=$1
```